# Rending partial in ajax request results in error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a partial I am trying to load though a create.js.erb, problem is that it loads fine when I can the partial from the view, but when I try to call it in the ajax action I get a NoMethodError for each  https://gist.github.com/4191176

**hashtag.rb**

```
class Hashtag < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :text, :profile_image_url, :from_user, :created_at, :tweet_id, :hashtag, :from_user_name

 def self.pull_hashtag(hashtag)
  hashtag_scrubbed = hashtag
  Twitter.search("%#{hashtag}", :lang => "en", :count => 100, :result_type => "mixed").results.map do |tweet|
    unless exists?(tweet_id: tweet.id)
        create!(
            tweet_id: tweet.id,
            text: tweet.text,
            profile_image_url: tweet.user.profile_image_url,
            from_user: tweet.from_user,
        from_user_name: tweet.user.name, 
            created_at: tweet.created_at,
        hashtag: hashtag
        )   
        end     
    end
  end
end
```

**hashtags_controller**

```
class HashtagsController < ApplicationController

    def home 

    end

    def vote
        @random_hashtags = Hashtag.order("RANDOM()").limit(4)
    end

    def show


    end

    def index

    end

    def create
        Hashtag.pull_hashtag(params[:hashtag])
        respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to vote_path }
        format.js
    end
     end
end
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$(".live-votes").slideDown(2222).prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'shared/vote_tweets', :object => @random_hashtags)) %>")
```

**_vote_tweet  partial**

```
<% @random_hashtags.each do |hashtag| %>
<div class="span4 twitter-spans-v1">
        <div id="tweet-block-v1" class="hashtag-tweet-database-container">
        <div class="tweet-block-border-v1">
        <div class="tweet-block-spacing-v1">
            <div class="twitter-block-author-v1">
            <a class="twitter-block-user-v1" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/<%= hashtag.from_user %>">
            <span class="twitter-author-image-v1"><img alt="" class="twitter-author-image-photo-v1" src="<%= hashtag.profile_image_url %>"></span>
            <span class="twitter-author-name-v1"><%= hashtag.from_user_name %></span>
            <span class="twitter-author-nickname-v1">@<%= hashtag.from_user %></span>
            </a>
            <iframe class="twitter-follow-button-v1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets/follow_button.html#align=right&button=grey&screen_name=<%= hashtag.from_user %>&show_count=false&show_screen_name=false&lang=en" allowtransparency="true">
            </iframe>
            </div>
        <div class="twitter-text-container-v1">
        <p class="twitter-text-field-v1">
        <%= hashtag.text %>
        </p>
        </div>
        <div class="twitter-footer-v1">
            <a class="twitter-view-details-v1" target="_blank"  href="https://twitter.com/<%= hashtag.from_user %>/statuses/<%= hashtag.tweet_id %>">
            <span class="tweet-date-v1"><%= hashtag.created_at.strftime("%d %b %Y") %></span>
            </a>
            <span class="twitter-vote-button-v1"><a href="#" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary">#WINNING</a>
</span>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
            <ul class="twitter-intent-ul-v1">
                <li class="twitter-intent-li-v1"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=<%= hashtag.tweet_id %>" class="twitter-intent-tweet" title="Reply"></a></li>
                <li class="twitter-intent-li-v1"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=<%= hashtag.tweet_id %>"  class="twitter-intent-retweet" title="Retweet"></a></li>
                <li class="twitter-intent-li-v1"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id=<%= hashtag.tweet_id %>"  class="twitter-intent-favorite" title="Favorite"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                    <% end %>
```

**error**

```
NoMethodError in Hashtags#create

Showing ./app/views/shared/_vote_tweets.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <% @random_hashtags.each do |hashtag| %>
2: <div class="span4 twitter-spans-v1">
3:      <div id="tweet-block-v1" class="hashtag-tweet-database-container">
4:      <div class="tweet-block-border-v1">
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/hashtags/create.js.erb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `:object => @random_hashtags` is NOT the same as giving @random_hashtags a value, without reading in the manual I think that is saying that you can use a variable `vote_tweet` in your partial "_vote_tveet" (which in that case has the value from `@random_hashtags` which MUST have been initiated). So if you still are using `@random_hashtags` in your partial and giving it a value in the controller, then you should skip `:object => @random_hashtags` in the line in create.js.erb

Answer (score 0):

It helps if I define         @random_hashtags = Hashtag.order("RANDOM()").limit(4)

in the create controller.